# Search for badge in Help Center returns no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, search, help-center

The search for [badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=badge) in the Help Center returns no results.

Since badges are part of the stackexchange model the search should list all references to "badge"-pages so that new users understand the meaning of badges.

At least should the result list the page [What are badges?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)

Comment: Thats odd. Also, [Badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=badge) and [Badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=badges) return different results.

Comment: Strangely, even "badges" doesn't return "What are badges?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug; we're looking into it and hope to have it fixed soon. Will update here when the issue is resolved.

UPDATE: That query (and all of them) should return results properly now, and the reason for the gap has been fixed. This issue shouldn't occur again, so if you are finding that search doesn't return results that you know exist, please submit a new bug report.